# PHP encode XHTML so ampersands encoded but not carets

Tags: php, xhtml

I want to encode entities to prevent XHTML from breaking though without encoding XHTML elements themselves. So leaving things like carets alone but encoding ampersands for example. The following is a minimal example of what I've tried messing with (yes I know it's not valid XHTML, just for testing purposes).

```
<?php
$b = '&<br />&';
//echo htmlentities($b,ENT_XHTML);
echo htmlspecialchars($b);
?>
```

The desired output...

> &
>
> &

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran It's just the formatting of the site, please reframe from chatty/nonconstructive comments that burn through the limited allowed comments.

Comment: Not sure you actually know what _carrots_ are …

Comment: so ... the desired output from `'&<br />&'` *is* `'&amp;<br />&amp;'`? What it is for `'&amp;<br />&'`?

Comment: @pozs THAT is one of the reasons/issues that I'm trying to stick to something built in to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to only encode ampersands, try this:

`echo str_replace('&', '&amp;', $b);`

**[Edit]**

If you're concerned about encoding instances of `&amp;` into `&amp;amp;`, you could use:

`echo preg_replace('/&[^(amp;)]/', '&amp;', $b);`

In this case `Test & &amp;` would be encoded as `Test &amp; $amp;`

Comment: To an extent yes though I'm going through php.net's documentation and PHP is usually pretty capable of doing specific things with built-in functions. If I can't find something and no one has a better answer I'll accept it though it means tracking down all the valid things that can create malformed XML.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no PHP function that only encodes ampersands (but there are loads, so who knows haha). If you're concerned about re-encoding existing instances of `&amp;` by mistake, you could use `preg_replace('/&[^(amp;)]/', '&amp;', $b);` :) x

Comment: I'm doing extensive testing of HTML entities to see what I need to encode and then I'll work on the duoble-encoded issue. It's possible to use arrays for replacement ($f (find) and $r (replace), the third item in $f replaces the third item in $r, etc.

Comment: Accepting it as the answer though I did post my own answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

My catch all...

```
<?php
$s = 'example & and &#38;.';
$f = array('&','&#38;#38;','&amp;','&#38;amp;');
$r = array('&#38;','&#38;','&#38;','&#38;');
echo str_replace($f,$r,$b);
?>
```

After creating a thousand entity test case, copying all the characters to an XHTML file all that truly needed to be encoded were the ampersands.

For those testing and encounter weird characters such as Ã make sure your page is encoded as UTF-8 and *not* windows-1252 for example.